# Norm of addition linear Operator

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, normed-spaces, lp-spaces, compact-operators

I want to find the operator norm of

\begin{equation}
Ax=(x_1+x_2,x_2+x_3,...)
\end{equation}

for x$\epsilon \ell_2$

I can show that this operator is bounded, as

\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=0}^\infty|x_i+x_{i+1}|^2<6\sum_{i=0}^\infty|x_i|^2
\end{equation}

Now in order to find the norm of this operator I search for $sup(Ax)$ for |x|=1. Thus I have that such a sequence is given by

\begin{equation}
(x_n)_k=\delta_{n,k}\rightarrow||Ax_{n,k}||=\sqrt{\sum_{i=0}^\infty|x_i+x_{i+1}|^2}=\sqrt{2}
\end{equation}

Does that allows me to conclude that this is the norm of my operator?
I think it does, because we search for the supremum. For instance, if we took, as our sequence to be the normalized Basel sequence, then we have a smaller norm.

or another argument could be that:

\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^\infty|x_i+x_{i+1}|^2 \leq 2\sum_{i=1}^\infty|x_i|^2+|x_{i+1}|^2=2\sum_{i=1}^\infty|x_i|^2-|x_1|^2.
\end{equation}

The last can be maximized for $|x_0|=0$

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your upper bounds are wrong: the sum $2\sum_{i=1}^\infty|x_ix_{i+1}|$ is missing.

Comment: Choose once for all whether your sequences begin at $i=0$ or $i=1.$

Answer (score 2):

First, your upper bounds are wrong: $|x_i+x_{i+1}|^2$ is not $\le|x_i|^2+|x_{i+1}|^2.$

Now, let $S$ be the shift operator, defined by $(S(x))_i=x_{i+1}.$ Then,
$$\|A\|=\|I+S\|\le\|I\|+\|S\|=2.$$

Conversely, for any positive integer $n,$ the sequence
$x:=\frac1{\sqrt n}\sum_{i=1}^n\delta_i$ has norm $1$ and its image
$$A(x)=\frac1{\sqrt n}\left(2\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\delta_i+\delta_n\right)$$
has norm $\sqrt{\frac{4n-3}n},$ so
$$\|A\|\ge\sup_{n\ge1}\sqrt{\frac{4n-3}n}=2.$$
Conclusion:
$$\|A\|=2.$$